# Trick in ssh config fails due to DNS lookups

Tags: ssh

We use a special ssh proxy which forces me to connect to servers using this syntax: `ssh myuser@privilegeduser@server.sub.domain@crappysshproxy.sub.domain`.
Btw: this proxy is called PSMP and belongs to the CyberArk product suite, it is *not* a jump or bastion host, although is seems to be similar because I do not have direct access to the servers and only the proxy is reachable.

To shorten this I tried the following `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host server
  HostName privilegeduser@server.sub.domain@crappysshproxy.sub.domain
  User myuser
```

Why I then do `ssh server` I get `ssh: Could not resolve hostname privilegeduser@server.sub.domain@crappysshproxy.sub.domain: Name or service not known`.

I tried to add these ...

```
CheckHostIP no
VerifyHostKeyDNS no
```

... to my ssh config and this ...

```
UseDNS no
```

... to the global ssh config.

Can I keep ssh from doing a DNS lookup and make it just use `User`+`HostName` for connections ?
I am *not* searching for a solution that makes me create shortcut bash scripts like `server.sh` that does the concatenation for me and I do *not* want to alias / replace the ssh command.

Comment: The best solution seems an alias indeed....

Comment: you might find better luck with ProxyJump; I haven't played with it enough to Answer.

Comment: Does this work? `HostName crappysshproxy.sub.domain`
and  `User myuser@privilegeduser@server.sub.domain`? I'm fairly sure ssh will split `user@host` on the last `@`, so I think that's equivalent to your ssh command-line that works.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro yes, but for various reasons it is not the solution

Comment: @JeffSchaller Unfortunately there is no netcat on the proxy

Comment: @filbranden This looks promising, but now I have a new problem because some calls to `ssh` are created with `publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no` automatically and this interferes (btw: no, I can not use keys for now ;-)) with my other settings. I will check this and update my question

Comment: @Marged, I hope you didn't get stuck looking at ProxyCommand in the man page, which demonstrates using `nc`; I was referring to `ProxyJump` which "`Specifies one or more jump proxies as [user@]host[:port]`"

Comment: @JeffSchaller I tried various approaches with the `-J` option, is this what you mean ?

Comment: Yes, @Marged; without knowing if it even works -- that was my best guess.

Comment: @filbranden I solved my problem, do you want to turn your comment into an answer ?

Comment: @Marged Will do! Thanks for confirming this worked for you! 

Comment: @Marged were there really issues with public key? If so, could you elaborate so we can include that in the answer? Or in the end it was actually working as expected, even with public key authentication? I can't think of a reason why it would interact badly with that... Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden I asked for all of this because Ansible spawns ssh for me. `ssh server` worked from the shell but Ansible adds more commands. So I had to add `--ask-pass` to my Ansible command line. This then worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass ssh an `user@host` setting, it will split that string on the *last* `@` and use the first part (with `@`s if present) as the user name.

So the equivalent way to specify that in your `.ssh/config` is:

```
Host server
  HostName crappysshproxy.sub.domain
  User myuser@privilegeduser@server.sub.domain
```